# Absolute positioning inside relative

Tags: css

I'm working with 100% width relative positioning, but need an absolute positioned child div or span to hold a jquery image slider.

Layout

------ width 100%-------

| img1 | slider | img2 |

Currently the slider span isn't being positioned inline like the other objects and overlapping

What I have so far:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44MFH/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="pic_container">
    <img src="http://www.image-and-text.com/pictures/whiskey_with_ice.jpg">  
    <span class="viewer"> 
       <img src="http://images.printsplace.co.uk/Content/Images/Products/46576/43569/Image_of_M101_1.jpg" alt="" class="active" />
        <img src="http://i.bosity.com/clothes_cache/261/12002348/3480000011312473207_12002348_1_image.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/examples/image-6.jpg" alt="" />
    </span>
    <img src="http://www.image-and-text.com/pictures/whiskey_with_ice.jpg">
</div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*slideshow*/

.viewer {
    font-size:0;
  display:inline;
}

.viewer IMG {
    position:absolute;

    z-index:8;
    width:50%;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.viewer IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

.viewer IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}


/*pics*/

.pic_container{
    font-size:0;
    display:inline;

    }


 .pic_container img {

    width:25%;
  vertical-align:top;
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve a little more, I dont get what is supposed to be relative and what is supposed to be absolute and where you want everything to be.

Comment: The viewer span contents needs to be absolute for the images to be be positioned on top of each other for the jquery transition to work (I think!) The pic_container class needs to be relative to allow for 100% width across all resolutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a wrapper to the viewer and removed the extra spacing between your outer images and the slideshow viewer using the html comment tags (this is better than setting font-size:0). I've adjusted the JS, so that the transition works. I've also cleaned up and reduced the amount of CSS needed.

**HTML**

```
<div class="picture-container">
    <img src="http://www.image-and-text.com/pictures/whiskey_with_ice.jpg" /><!--
        --><div class="viewer">
        <img src="http://images.printsplace.co.uk/Content/Images/Products/46576/43569/Image_of_M101_1.jpg" class="active" />
        <img src="http://i.bosity.com/clothes_cache/261/12002348/3480000011312473207_12002348_1_image.jpg" />
        <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/examples/image-6.jpg" /> 
        </div><!--
    --><img src="http://www.image-and-text.com/pictures/whiskey_with_ice.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {margin:0;padding:0}
.picture-container > img {display:inline-block;width:25%;}
.viewer {display:inline-block;position:relative;width:50%;vertical-align:top;}
.viewer img {position:absolute;width:100%;}
```

**JS**

```
function slideSwitch() {
  var transitionDuration = 1000;
    var active = $('.viewer img.active');
    var next = $('.viewer img:first').insertAfter(active);
    active.removeClass('active').fadeOut(transitionDuration);
    next.addClass('active').hide().fadeIn(transitionDuration);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.viewer img.active').insertAfter('.viewer img:last');
    setInterval("slideSwitch()", 4000);
});
```

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ry7Su/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Positioning looks great! The only issue is the JS, the transition no longer fades into other images, it now fades to white and then the next image

Comment: You can move the fadeIn outside of the fadeOut. By specifying the fadeIn as part of the callback...it doesn't start until the fadeOut has finished. If you put the call to fadeIn at the same level as fadeOut...they will run together (maybe a tiny bit out of sync, but depends on the client's machine). I'll adjust my answer in case you want the example.

Comment: Thanks for the example. It seems to render the the fade in image under the image which is fading out, just for a second or 2.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've modified my original answer to address the issue.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Do you have any recommendations for learning more complex Jquery?

Comment: http://jquery.com/ has some excellent resources. However, I really enjoyed the book "jQuery: Novice to Ninja" (http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/). I have always been partial to contextual-based learning. Books like that tend to help me make better use of the documentation sites. I also think it really helps to understand CSS selectors...as, I still find myself learning little things here and there.

Answer (score 0):

The following changes will solve your problem.

This is based on your code. You can tweak it to make it shorter.

HTML part:

```
<div class="pic_container">
     <div class="leftDiv">
        <img src="http://www.image-and-text.com/pictures/whiskey_with_ice.jpg">  
     </div><!--
  --><div class="viewerWrapper"><div class="viewer">
        <img src="http://images.printsplace.co.uk/Content/Images/Products/46576/43569/Image_of_M101_1.jpg" alt="" class="active" />
        <img src="http://i.bosity.com/clothes_cache/261/12002348/3480000011312473207_12002348_1_image.jpg" alt="" />
        <img src="http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/images/examples/image-6.jpg" alt="" />
     </div></div><!--
  --><div class="rightDiv">
        <img src="http://www.image-and-text.com/pictures/whiskey_with_ice.jpg">
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS Part:

```
.pic_container {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    }
.leftDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    position:relative;
}
.rightDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    position:relative;
}
.viewerWrapper {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.viewer {
    width:100%;
}
.leftDiv IMG, .rightDiv IMG, .viewer IMG {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.viewer IMG {
    z-index:8;
    position: absolute;
}
.viewer IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}
.viewer IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/FTEan/

Answer (score 0):

try to give `pic_container` `position: relative;` and try to give `viewer` `display: inline-block;` this might work. `pic_container` could may also be `display: inline-block;`